# How to use form data from one site to login to another form on another website?

Tags: javascript, php, python, html, ajax

I have multiple accounts on many different social networking websites and email providers like Gmail, Outlook, Facebook, etc. It's a burden to shuffle between these accounts and hence I am trying to create a webpage that has a webform which has the following. 
1) Username
2) E-mail
3) Password
4) Launch button
This form is the only page that I will be designing. I want this webform to be a one-click autologin thing(if that makes sense) for all the other websites. Basically if I enter all my details into this form and click on the launch button, it automatically logs in to services like outlook by using the email and password that I entered and redirect me to the outlook homepage. I am trying to find out ways to make this work but have had no luck.

Comment: Password managers like LastPass provide a similar function FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave commented services like LastPass provide a similar service where they manage all of your passwords and can auto-login to some sites when they load.  There are also application-based versions of this like KeePass.  If you use Chrome you can also utilize Google Password (it will generate and store unique passwords for you that are parented by your Google account).  I would also recommend against using the same User and Password across multiple services (this is where Google Password or LastPass are useful, as all the passwords are unique).  Having unique strong passwords is *very* important.

See https://www.webroot.com/us/en/resources/tips-articles/how-do-i-create-a-strong-password for some password practices.